# How to keep generic filepath in @PropertySource annotation for both windows and linux

Tags: linux, spring-boot, window, filepath

I have following configuration code in my spring boot application:-

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
@PropertySource(value = "file://${CONFIG_PATH}/folder/application.properties"),
@PropertySource(value = "file://${CONFIG_PATH}/folder/application-log.properties"),
@PropertySource(value = "file://${CONFIG_PATH}/folder/application-persistence.properties"),
@PropertySource(value = "file://${CONFIG_PATH}/folder/application-environment.properties")
})
public class PopulateFixturesConfig {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
}
```

Above code executes on Linux Server and I have Windows on local machine. So when I have to do development i have to change, I have to add extra "/" after file like this:

```
 @PropertySource(value = "file:///${CONFIG_PATH}/folder/application-environment.properties")
```

and again when i have to commit the code i have to remove that extra "/".

Is there any way to keep the path generic for both windows and linux.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java greater than Java 7, then you can do like this

```
String configPath= System.getProperty("CONFIG_PATH");

java.nio.file.Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(configPath, "some", "dir", "path1", "path2")
```

java.nio.file.Path have lot of methods which can give you the absolute path in string

If you are using Java less than Java 7 then use `File.separator`